# Receiving a client error message while using the discord api

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to create an admin bot using the discord API. This is the set I have as of yet,

```
ACCESS_TOKEN = ""
client = discord.Client()

#this identifies when the bot is online and ready to listen for messages
@client.event
async def on_read():
    print('Bot is now online and active')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return 
    
    await message.channel.send('Hello')



client.run(ACCESS_TOKEN)
```

When I run it I get a string of errors which I am not sure as to what they mean.

```
ile "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 969, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1080, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1110, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 528, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 188, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 974, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vipashashah/TCMprojects/midterm APIs2.0/DiscordAPI", line 20, in <module>
    client.run(' ')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 300, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 192, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 520, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 535, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 892, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1051, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1020, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 971, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')]
```

I removed my access token for security but everything else is the same. I installed the discord package so not sure what went wrong.

Comment: Don't you need `const` in front of ACCESS_TOKEN and client?

Comment: @JeremiahDuane This is python

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs That explains it lol.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem related to python 3.10 on MacOS.

Easy solution: go back to python 3.9

Look here for more details:

https://githubhot.com/repo/piekstra/tplink-cloud-api/issues/63